# Binding SubState enum based on MainState enum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a label value to a substate enum, based on the mainstate. Each Mainstate has  a different substate enum, that is why when the mainstate changes I need to rebind the label to a different substate enum. But how can I do this is the corresponding XAML code.

This is the class containing the 3 state enums (1 mainstate & 2 substates)

```
public class Motor : ObservableObject
{
    public enum STATE
    {
        IDLE,
        CALIBRATE,
        GO_HOME
    }

    public enum CALIBRATE_TRACK
    {
        SUB_STATE_C1,
        SUB_STATE_C2,
        SUB_STATE_C3,
        SUB_STATE_C4,
    }

    public enum HOMING
    {
        SUB_STATE_H1,
        SUB_STATE_H2,
        SUB_STATE_H3,
    }

    private STATE _currentState = STATE.IDLE;
    public STATE CurrentState
    {
        get { return _currentState; }
        set { _currentState = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentState"); }
    }

    private CALIBRATE_TRACK _calibrateTrackState = CALIBRATE_TRACK.SUB_STATE_C1;
    public CALIBRATE_TRACK CalibrateTrackState
    {
        get { return _calibrateTrackState; }
        set { _calibrateTrackState = value; OnPropertyChanged("CalibrateTrackState"); }
    }


    private HOMING _homeingState = HOMING.SUB_STATE_H1;
    public HOMING HomeingState
    {
        get { return _homeingState; }
        set { _homeingState = value; OnPropertyChanged("HomeingState"); }
    }
}
```

So when the `CurrentState` for example changes to `CALIBRATE` then I want to bind to substate item `CalibrateTrackState` and when the `CurrentState` changes to `GO_HOME` then I want to bind to the substate item `HomeingState`

This is the XAML code I have so far:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                    <Binding Path="motor.CurrentState"/>
                    <Binding Path="motor.xxx"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

So the binding of the CurrentState is no problem. But I don't know how to bind the substate. In the example above, I've added a placeholder for the substate location called `motor.xxx`.

Then the resulting output should be something like

```
"CALIBRATE - SUB_STATE_C1"
```

when the mainstate in `CALIBRATE` and the substate of Calibrate is `SUB_STATE_C1`

Comment: create additional property in Motor class (e.g. `string CurrentStateText`) and bind Label to it. Update of CurrentStateText should happen in Motor in this case

Comment: How do you change the States? In the the Code and the UI should react to it?

Comment: The states are indeed changed in code and the UI should follow these states. The states are not changed through the UI itself.

Comment: @RoelBalink I have added an answer assuming there is some UI interaction for the States change. I think some part of the code you can take it and implement in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @ASh already said in the Comments, i suggest you to create a `Property` which formats the whole State.

Property:

```
public string CurrentStateText
{
    get
    {
        if (CurrentState.Equals(STATE.IDLE))
            return CurrentState;

        else if (CurrentState.Equals(STATE.CALIBRATE))
            return String.Format("{0} - {1}", CurrentState, CalibrateTrackState);

        else if (CurrentState.Equals(STATE.GO_HOME))
            return String.Format("{0} - {1}", CurrentState, HomeingState);

        else return "Invalid STATE!";
    }
}
```

Binding

```
<Label Content="{Binding CurrentStateText}" />
```

And you must notify the UI when some of the States have changed. To do this, simply add
`OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStateText");` to all the State `Setter` like this

```
set { _currentState = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentState"); OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStateText"); }
set { _calibrateTrackState = value; OnPropertyChanged("CalibrateTrackState"); OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStateText"); }
etc.
```

Note: I don't have my IDE at hand, so there may be syntax/spelling Errors in the code.

Comment: This indeed seems to fit my needs. I didn't think of creating the string in the motor class and let the individual states create the OnPropertyChanged of that string. At first I didn't understand @ASh his answer but now I get it

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps,

1. Create a string property called "SubState" in your ViewModel and bind it to your label as below,

   ```
     private string _subState;    
     public string SubState    
     {
        get { return _subState; }
        set { _subState = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
     }
   ```
2. Update your xaml to bind to SubState string property.

   ```
   <Label Content="{Binding SubState}" />
   ```
3. Assuming you have a command or an event for selection change event to check when STATE has changed and on the event handler, update the "SubState" text as below.

Note:- For demo, I am using a event handler in code-behind for a combobox which is bound to List

```
     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}" Grid.Row="0"
             x:Name="CmbState" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
     </ComboBox>
```

4. Here is my complete xaml

   ```
       <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CmbState" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
         </ComboBox>
         <Label Content="{Binding SubState}" Grid.Row="1" />
       </Grid>
   ```
5. SelectionChanged event on code-behind

   ```
          private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,
          SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             var cmbSender = sender as ComboBox;
             var state = (Motor.STATE) cmbSender.SelectedItem;
             mainVm.SetState(state);
         }
   ```
6. Here is the SetState method of my ViewModel

   ```
         public void SetState(object selectedState)
         {
             if(selectedState.ToString() == STATE.IDLE.ToString())
             {
                 SubState = CurrentState.ToString();
             }
             else if(selectedState.ToString() == STATE.CALIBRATE.ToString())
             {
                 SubState = CalibrateTrackState.ToString();
             }
             else
             {
                 SubState = HomeingState.ToString();
             }
         }
   ```
7. Declare a List and bind to your combo-box and initialize States list object in your ViewModel constructor as below,

   ```
             public List<STATE> States { get; set; }
             States = new List<STATE>
             {
                 STATE.IDLE,
                 STATE.CALIBRATE,
                 STATE.GO_HOME
             };
   ```

Note:- MainVM is my ViewModel and I personally feel Motor class should contain only data members and not any property changed events or someother thing related to VM which has to do. So, I have moved certain items from Motor class to my ViewModel.

See my complete ViewModel

```
  class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
      {

          public List<STATE> States { get; set; }

          private string _subState;
          public string SubState
          {
              get { return _subState; }
              set { _subState = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
          }

          public MainVM()
          {
              States = new List<STATE>
              {
                  STATE.IDLE,
                  STATE.CALIBRATE,
                  STATE.GO_HOME
              };

              SubState = CurrentState.ToString();
          }



          public void SetState(object selectedState)
          {
              if(selectedState.ToString() == STATE.IDLE.ToString())
              {
                  SubState = CurrentState.ToString();
              }
              else if(selectedState.ToString() == STATE.CALIBRATE.ToString())
              {
                  SubState = CalibrateTrackState.ToString();
              }
              else
              {
                  SubState = HomeingState.ToString();
              }
          }

          private STATE _currentState = STATE.IDLE;
          public STATE CurrentState
          {
              get { return _currentState; }
             set { _currentState = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentState"); }
         }

         private CALIBRATE_TRACK _calibrateTrackState = CALIBRATE_TRACK.SUB_STATE_C1;
          public CALIBRATE_TRACK CalibrateTrackState
          {
              get { return _calibrateTrackState; }
              set { _calibrateTrackState = value; OnPropertyChanged("CalibrateTrackState"); }
          }

          private HOMING _homeingState = HOMING.SUB_STATE_H1;
          public HOMING HomeingState
          {
              get { return _homeingState; }
              set { _homeingState = value; OnPropertyChanged("HomeingState"); }
          }

          protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
          {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          }

          public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      }
```

Note:- I have pasted code which you might not require entirely, since I am not sure on how you are checking the STATE change, so I assumed a combobox bind to your ViewModel object and I created the rest of the story as above mentioned.

Hope I made it clear, in case ff you have any other doubts, don't hesitate to ask again.

Comment: This indeed looks like a usable answer, I'm trying to implement it. I think the difference is that instead of triggering on the combox selectionchanged event, I think I have to implement a contentchanged event of the label containing the CurrentState binding. But I think I still have a problem when 'CalibrateTrackState' changes but the Currentstate is already on 'CALIBRATE' and doesn't change.

Comment: I don't see Label Content change makes any sense or not the right way of doing the things, if your intention to check the property bind to Label is changed, is there any other way that you can track of the property which is bound to Label from some other control state change.

Comment: @RoelBalink Give a try and share the code snippet if there is any further issue.